# How to pass apostrophe from python to psql?? 'DatabaseError' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, postgresql, sql-injection

I am using locally host postgresql database 9.6. which connect like this

```
conn_string = """host='localhost'
                     dbname='contact_form'
                     user='{0}'
                     password='{1}'""".format(db_username,
                                              db_password)

conLocal = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
```

I have name = "Mark's Dane", which contain apostrophe
which I want to pass into database, so I have following query

```
query = """SELECT pet_name
                   FROM pet
                   WHERE name = '{0}'""".format(name)
```

Then I run following code:

```
pet_name = read_sql(query, conLocal)
```

However, I am getting following error :

'DatabaseError' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: [tag:psql] is the command-line client. You mean [tag:postgresql]

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `format` for interpolating values into SQL strings.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection
- http://bobby-tables.com

Instead, use the `execute` method, passing a tuple of parameters, e.g.

```
conn.execute("""SELECT pet_name
               FROM pet
               WHERE name = %s""", (name,))
```

Note the use of the 1-tuple `(name,)`.

See the Python DBI-API documentation and the psycopg2 manual for more.

Comment: I used above code i get following error: 'ProgrammingError' object has no attribute 'encode

Comment: @KppatelPatel ... and the full stack trace? I fail to see how that error can come from here.

Comment: ProgrammingError: unterminated quoted string at or near "'s"

Comment: @KppatelPatel That's a *different error*, and also not a full stack trace. This isn't a "debug your code for you" service, and there's code you aren't showing (like whatever the `read_sql` function is). But this is is the cause of the problem you mentioned with single quotes.